# Unable to access PDS in z/OS unix shell

Tags: shell, unix, mainframe, zos

I'm trying to copy a text file from within the z/OS unix shell to a PDS titled P2.OUTPUT($010), but whenever i run the command cp file.txt "//P2.OUTPUT($010)" i get an error stating that P2.OUTPUT(-sh10) is an invalid location. For whatever reason, whenever I run the command $010 becomes -sh10. I've tried putting $010 in '' and a few other things but no matter what I do it doesn't seem to work. I believe it's an issue with accessing the file and not with the cp command because I can't view the contents of the member using the cat command either, and any error trying to access the member using any command lists it as -sh10 instead of $010. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the unix shell interprets `$0` as an environment-variable that has the value `-sh` as can be seen when using `echo $0`, so your command becomes `cp file.txt "//P2.OUTPUT(-sh10)"`.

Try escaping the `$` using a backslash: `cp file.txt "//P2.OUTPUT(\$010)"`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it worked perfectly!