# Im not seeing Datasets on the envirnoment z/OS unix shell

Tags: shell, unix, posix, zos

Just to give the context I had the same doubt of the our coleague @JOB in this Thread: ["Unable to Access PDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001256/unable-to-access-pds-in-z-os-unix-shell) , ok its was solved. 
 I have one question which is related to: Why when us are on that envirnoment Linux, from the command TSO OMVS, we aren't able to see us Dataset's, PDS's?
 Or Is that possible?

Comment: You know that OMVS isn't Linux? Have you tried `ls` for a PDS which you have access to using the correct name format for a ZFS dataset? What result did you get?

Comment: Thank you by your attention Bill, yes you are right I still not had realized it which not is pure Linux, its compliant with.. its build into the ZO/s.. I not know , I dont know how should do for reach the PDS directory when Im in OMVS.. supose the path is >> "id.P2.Output(something.)..I really not see this pds..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to understand that z/OS-datasets and OMVS files live in two different worlds:
z/OS datasets do have a name that consists of a series of qualifiers but are not really organized in a hierarchical manner, they are distributed over a cluster of (virtual) disks and you have a couple of catalogs to find them again. There are no such things as directories: while you might have a dataset named `MY.COOL.DSN`, there might not be an object that is called `MY.COOL` or it might be an ordinary dataset as well.

OMVS files on the other hand live in a filesystem that has a hierarchical structure. Each file might reside in a directory, that might be in another directory etc. In total you end up with a tree of directories with a single root-directory and files as leaves.

To realize this in OMVS you create z/OS datasets that contain hierarchical filesystems - either HFS or z/FS - each with its own directory-tree. Upon installation one of those is mounted as the root-filesystem and addressed via `/` and you might mount other HFS or z/FS filesystems on any point further down the directory-tree, so that it is added as a subtree.

If you are familiar with Linux you can compare the HFS and z/FS datasets as disk-partitions that can be mounted in your system.

Long story short: when navigating via `cd` and `ls` you are moving through the directory-tree that consists of all the mounted z/FS and HFS datasets, but there is no defined place that contains the ordinary z/OS datasets - and there can't be since they are not organized in a tree-structure.